# Is there any difference between DOUBLE(n, 0) and BIGINT(n) MySQL Datatypes?

Tags: mysql

Is there any reason to use a DOUBLE(n, 0) over a BIGINT(n) in MySQL?  If the data will never have a decimal portion, is there any reason to store as a DOUBLE?

Comment: DOUBLE uses imprecise floating point, so it should actually not be used. It could be used to save space for huge n, but I doubt it. BIGINT has a max n of 18-19, DOUBLE even less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one reason to ever use `DOUBLE` or `FLOAT` in MySQL -- if scale and/or storage efficiency are important, but precision is not.  This is not a limitation of MySQL, but rather of floating point numbers in general, which is that they are stored as *approximate* values.

Integers will be stored cleanly up to only about 2⁵³, which is smaller than `BIGINT`.  Most (though not all) integers beyond that range will be stored as a value that is only close to correct.

> Floating-point numbers sometimes cause confusion because they are approximate and not stored as exact values. A floating-point value as written in an SQL statement may not be the same as the value represented internally. Attempts to treat floating-point values as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies.
>
> — [Problems with Floating Point Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html)

For integers, use one of the `*INT` types.  For decimal, use `DECIMAL`.